# Authenticated API request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, api-testing

I am performing API testing using Jmeter, we have a API request which require authentication.

When I make a call http://localhost:3001/city/latitude/longitude (GET method) it returns `User is not authorized`. And to get authorization you require to call http://localhost:3001/user (POST method) passing username in json format.

So, how can I make a authorized call on http://localhost:3001/city/latitude/longitude

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what kind of "authorization" you get by sending POST request to  http://localhost:3001/user it might be:

- some "token" which you need to add to request body
- some [Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) which contains authorization data.
- some [Cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) which indicates whether user is authorized or not.

So in any case you need to design your test as follows:

1. POST request to /user

   - Extract authorization bearer
2. GET request to /city/lat/lon which has either token or authentication passed via [HTTP Header Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) or [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)